# What is the mean of this error?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uistoryboard

My application is working very well for first time in the sumilator, when I rerun my app in simulator and press some button, I get this type of error. I am using Local DB, so I thought maybe it is reason for taking this error message?

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'UIViewController-Lat-JX-Ucy' and directory 'MainStoryboard_iPad.storyboardc''
>
> *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x1bdc012 0x18e9e7e 0x1bdbdeb 0xa49ef9 0xc7554a 0xc75b43 0xc75c14 0x18fd705 0x8312c0 0x831258 0x8f2021 0x8f257f 0x8f16e8 0x860cef 0x860f02 0x83ed4a 0x830698 0x27bedf9 0x27bead0 0x1b51bf5 0x1b51962 0x1b82bb6 0x1b81f44 0x1b81e1b 0x27bd7e3 0x27bd668 0x82dffc 0x2d9d 0x2cc5)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

Comment: Is there any other context in the log like "The class MyViewController is not key value coding compliant ..."

Answer (score 0):

It simply means that Xcode was not able find a nib file named "UIViewController-Lat-JX-Ucy" in your project. Make sure that you have a nib file named like that.

Comment: This is a file that's generated while compiling a storyboard, it will be in the output of the build inside of the '*.storyboardc' file, but won't be in the project.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not related with your DB, it is saying that it has a problem loading the UIViewController-Lat-JX-Ucy view from the MainStoryboard_iPad storyboard. How are you loading it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I was loading a new bundle that contained **almost** the same storyboards as the previous bundle.

In my case in original storyboard there was an OriginalViewController in one container, but in updated bundle that container had NewViewController. When trying to open this container using new storyboard I had a crash because no view controller with previous id (Lat-JX-Ucy in your case) was found in new storyboard - it was in the old storyboard.

My solution was to clear cache of the previously loaded bundle before loading a new one. Everything is well explained [here](http://michelf.ca/blog/2010/killer-private-eraser/)