# iOS storyboard weird error - 'NSInternalInconsistencyException' (Main.storyboardc)

Tags: ios, storyboard

i am working on my xcode project. i have just clean the project and try to build the project. dont know what happen i got very weird error.

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'UIViewController-bSa-xT-TPG' and directory 'Main.storyboardc'

Don't know which code i have to check!! i refereed some question related to this but can't solve my problem.

**EDIT:-**

when i tried to search `storyboardc` in Find navigator. it gives result like this.

[image: Storyboardc in Find navigator]

**Edit:**

I am also not able to see storyboard in build phases. i have tried it to add manually but still it appears in red symbol like this.

[image: Storyboard not detected in build phases]

Comment: Have you use any xib(With out Story board) file?

Comment: yes . i use `LaunchScreen.xib` only.

Comment: "Main.storyboardc' ? An extra 'c' in the name?

Comment: yup. dont know ? i have edit post please check.

Comment: The 'c' is added by the compiler

Comment: Yes be problem is storyboard's extension

Comment: @lostInTransit :- lol ! don't know but see in image search result shows `storyboardc`

Comment: Have you set your initialview controller in storyboar?

Comment: yes i have set my view controller as initialview controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My problem is solved. don't know is it correct method or not. i have move `Main.storyboard`from `Base.lproj` to any other folder. then delete `Main.storyboard` from this folder and again drag and drop it in `mainbundle` means `project window` and tick mark all in `localization` setting. then  **clean and build** and run the project successfully.

Comment: Just removing and re-adding the storyboard worked in my case. I did rename it at the same time (I had been intending to for a while), so I'm not sure if that affected anything or not.

Comment: Just removing and re-adding the storyboard and 
I just cleaned the project using cmd+shift+K. Then clean build folder too using opt+cmd+shift+K.
Finally this worked.

Answer (score 1):

Try a Cmd+Alt+Shift+K (clean build folder) and build. That should resolve the issue if it is just an inconsistency.

There could be other reasons to getting this error as well

1. There is a possibility you are accessing a UIControl before it is instantiated. That could also cause this issue - and that is what generally does lead to such issues
2. instantiating the wrong view controller - related to 1 in a way (check your hierarchy and instances created in the App Delegate)
3. A start up issue - are you doing anything on startup which might delay the loading of the app?

Comment: i tried with Cmd+Alt+Shift+K but not solved. i have checked hierarchy , no issue in this. in startup it loads splash from .xib but it working fine. splash screen comeup and then this error come. and i dont think this is memory issue.

Comment: You might want to do a debug and check. If any of the ui controls in your views are accessed before the view is created (say in initWithCoder:), you will get this error.

Comment: i am new in ios. so i don't know how to use debugger. can you give me the link or something which show to process or info of debugging.

Comment: Just put in breakpoints in the AppDelegate and your ViewController's load methods or initializers. Step through them and see where it fails (http://jeffreysambells.com/2014/01/14/using-breakpoints-in-xcode - in case you need help with breakpoints)

Answer (score 1):

This can be due to same named storyboard ID assigned to two different view Controller present in one storyboard. So simple solution to find this, search the name of the controller which is causing "Nib could not found" in main.storyboard. in my case, it was "MarksViewController" that I have used accidentally two times as Storyboard ID.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16353881/1311272) is relevant. I think the important part of the error is "UIViewController-bSa-xT-TPG" and not the storyboardc file.

Make sure that you have a "UIViewController-bSa-xT-TPG" in your Storyboard/XIB. You can right click the storyboard and chose "open as source code" (to switch back, simply right click again and chose "open as 'Interface builder - storyboard'").

Search for "UIViewController-bSa-xT-TPG", if it does not exist then you have a problem. If you search for "UIViewController-bSa-xT-TPG" in the project, what do you get?

Comment: Georgii-Hemmi:- i have tried this option but not success.